# Why is Ryuunosuke Akasaka's hair so long?

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

Why is Ryuunosuke Akasaka's hair so long? It makes him look like a girl. Is there some explanation to that in the series besides this being a possible consequence of being a hikkikomori?

Also, Maid-chan (the AI created by him) has a similar appearance. Ryuunosuke said that he wants to turn her into a real person (sentient AI?) one day. I suspect this may be related.

Also! Ryuunosuke has gynophobia (he's *so* afraid of females). This might also be the reason (in a way).

[image: Ryuunosuke Akasaka]

Comment: I assume the person in the picture I put in is Ryunosuke Akasaka, because this is the person who came up on all of the google searches. I've never seen the show, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine his long hair is probably only to make him look like a  hikkomori and support his personality traits. Perhaps it was decided that long hair and an androgynous figure would lend itself well to a reserved character.

His maid is suspected to be based on an old classmate, perhaps a first love or childhood friend. So it appears that isn't related.

[image]

Personally, I wouldn't imagine his fear of women would be a factor in his hairstyle choice, There are many other characters in anime that have a fear of the opposite gender, but there's no obvious trend for those characters to have hair of the opposite gender's style.

Overall, I think his hair is long for no other reason than the original mangaka's design decision.

Comment: I guess hikikomori part makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Akasaka Ryuunosuke's hair might be very long because since he's a hikkikomori; he rarely goes out, so he wouldn't go to a hairstylist or something like that for a pretty long time, but might still go occasionally to keep it neat.  His bangs are longer than most people would keep their bangs, so that also sort of proves my point.

I watched the anime, and I think the mangaka designed him this way to make him look really mysterious. He's always a sort of shadowy character with a mysterious past, and he's also the only character which we don't know anything about his family, which makes him more mysterious, unless you count the two new characters in the last episode - Hase Kanna and Himemiya Iori.

Comment: I think it could even be that he trims his bangs himself, no stylist involved. Would be a perfect fit for a shut-in personality. Interesting point.

Answer (score 0):

They probably just like having long hair. I mean... I'm a guy too and my hair is almost as long as his. I don't have long hair because of any fancy reason, I have it because I just like having long hair.